# N balls and M boxes, probability that there is at least 1 box contains at least 2 balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> I have $N$ balls and $M$ boxes. Balls are thrown to the boxes at random.
>   What is the probability that there is at least 1 box contains at least 2 balls?

Thank you very much

Comment: Look at Wikipedia, or elsewhere, under Birthday Problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

We first make the probability model explicit. Imagine the balls are thrown one at a time, and that a ball is equally likely to land in any of the boxes. So our set of outcomes is the set of all ordered $N$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_N)$, where each $a_i$ is an integer between $1$ and $M$. We are assuming all outcomes are equally likely.

Note that there are $M^N$ outcomes.

We find the probability $p$ of the **complementary event** that all boxes have at most one ball. Then our required probability is $1-p$.

So we count the number of outcomes in which the balls land in distinct boxes. Assume that $M\ge N$.

The first ball has $M$ choices. For every such choice, the second ball has $M-1$ choices. For every choice we make for where the first two balls land, there are $M-2$ choices for the third, and so on. So the number of outcomes in which all the balls land in distinct boxes is $M(M-1)(M-2)\cdots(M-N+1)$. It follows that 
$$p=   \frac{M(M-1)(M-2)\cdots (M-N+1)}{M^N}.$$
 The answer to the posted question is then $1-p$.

**Remark:** This is a well-known problem, usually called the *Birthday Problem*.  There is a large literature.  Note that the two other answers currently given are **different** from the one above. That is because the implicit model they use is that all solutions $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M)$ of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_M=N$, where $x_i$ is the number of balls in Box $i$, are equally likely. That will not be the case if balls are "thrown" according to the model we described.

Answer (score 0):

The complementary event $A$ is that all $M$ boxes contain $0$ or $1$ balls. There are $\binom{M}{N}$ possibilities for this (assuming this to be zero if $N>M$). Overall, we have $R=\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}$ possibilities to distribute $N$ balls on $M$ boxes, so $P(A)=\frac{\binom{M}{N}}{R}$ and thus the probability of your event is $1-P(A)$.

Comment: This assumes that all indistinguishable distributions are equiprobable. The formulation in the question sounds to me more like the balls are independently thrown into the boxes with equal probabilities for the boxes. Of course if people ask questions about probabilities without specifying a distribution, it's anybody's guess what they meant...